# Difference in app.jar size when building the jar in circleci build and deploying to app service v/s when looking under wwwroot on appservice host

Tags: gradle, jar, azure-web-app-service, circleci

I have a java spark web service that I am building using gradle. I am trying to build and deploy the jar to azure app service using circleci. Upon adding intermediate 'ls' within my circleci tasks, I can see the size of the jar file upon building is large enough and covers all dependencies within the jar. However, when I ssh to my appservice host post deployment completion , the jar that I find under /home/site/wwwroot is of considerable smaller size and does not cover all my dependencies, and instead only contains my original source code files.

Here is my circleci config

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  gradle: circleci/gradle@3.0.0

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:11-jdk
    working_directory: ~/repo
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - gradle-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}
            - gradle-dependencies-
      - run: gradle dependencies
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: gradle-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}

      - run: gradle test

      - run:
          name: "Build and Package JAR"
          command: |
            ./gradlew customFatJar
            ls -rlt ~/repo/build/libs/app.jar

      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ~/repo
          paths:
            - build
  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.7
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install azure-cli
          command: |
            curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
      - run:
          name: Login to Azure
          command: |
            az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $APP_SECRET --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID

      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/repo

      - run:
          name: Deploy to Azure App Service
          command: |
            az webapp up --sku F1 -n 'CikService' -l 'East US' --runtime 'JAVA:11-java11' --resource-group 'Cik' -p 'P1v2' --os-type 'Linux'

      - run:
          name: Deploy Code
          command: |
            ls -rlt ~/repo/build/libs/app.jar
            az webapp deployment source config-zip -g 'Cik' -n 'CikService' --src ~/repo/build/libs/app.jar

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main
```

Here is the build log from circleci

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
ls -rlt ~/repo/build/libs/app.jar
az webapp deployment source config-zip -g 'Cik' -n 'CikService' --src ~/repo/build/libs/app.jar

**-rw-r--r-- 1 circleci circleci 7401147 Jun 29 08:03 /home/circleci/repo/build/libs/app.jar**
Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
{
  "active": true,
  "author": "N/A",
  "author_email": "N/A",
  "build_summary": {
    "errors": [],
    "warnings": []
  },
  "complete": true,
  "deployer": "Push-Deployer",
  "end_time": "2023-06-29T08:06:30.6786105Z",
  "id": "ec11ce4a-71d7-42b2-836f-f01c74015916",
  "is_readonly": true,
  "is_temp": false,
  "last_success_end_time": "2023-06-29T08:06:30.6786105Z",
  "log_url": "https://cikservice.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log",
  "message": "Created via a push deployment",
  "progress": "",
  "received_time": "2023-06-29T08:05:22.3944098Z",
  "site_name": "cikservice",
  "start_time": "2023-06-29T08:05:23.9412019Z",
  "status": 4,
  "status_text": "",
  "url": "https://cikservice.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest"
}
CircleCI received exit code 0
```

When I ssh to app service host, I see the size of the jar is considerably smaller

```
d8af2b6b9e31:/home# ls -rlt /home/site/wwwroot/app.jar 
-rwxrwxrwx    1 nobody   nobody       10562 Jun 28 06:49 /home/site/wwwroot/app.jar
d8af2b6b9e31:/home# 

d8af2b6b9e31:/home# jar -tf /home/site/wwwroot/app.jar 
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx2300M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
org/
org/example/
org/example/repository/
org/example/repository/CikRepository.class
org/example/repository/SECRepository.class
org/example/enumeration/
org/example/enumeration/ReportType.class
org/example/http/
org/example/http/HttpHelper.class
org/example/external/
org/example/external/ExternalUrl.class
org/example/Main.class
log4j2.xml
d8af2b6b9e31:/home#
```

You can see above there are no dependencies included . Any perspective on what could be causing the jar to shrink post deployment ?

Tried looking up online for answers but did not get anything specific to my problem .

Also added a bunch of debug messages within my circleci build to ensure I was looking building the right jar and also confirmed the contents of the jar after running gradle within circleci build.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `az webapp deployment source config-zip` which deploys the app as a zip, Try to use

Below command [**reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deploy):-

```bash
az webapp deploy --resource-group siliconrg11 --name valleywebapp32 --type jar --src-path "<path to Jar file>"
```

**Complete CircleCI yml script:-**

```yaml
Original config.yml file:
version: 2.1
orbs:
  gradle: circleci/gradle@3.0.0

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:11-jdk
    working_directory: ~/repo
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - gradle-dependencies-{{ checksum \"build.gradle\" }}
            - gradle-dependencies-
      - run: gradle dependencies
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: gradle-dependencies-{{ checksum \"build.gradle\" }}

      - run: gradle test

      - run:
          name: \"Build and Package JAR\"
          command: |
            ./gradlew customFatJar
            ls -rlt ~/repo/build/libs/app.jar

      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ~/repo
          paths:
            - build
  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.7
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install azure-cli
          command: |
            curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
      - run:
          name: Login to Azure
          command: |
            az login --service-principal -u xxxxa31435cb -p xxxx13-CS0ifbLE --tenant xxxx45-4ce4-99ed-af9038592395

      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/repo

      - run:
          name: Deploy to Azure App Service
          command: |
            az webapp up --sku 'P1V3' -n 'valleywebapp32' -l 'Australia East' --runtime 'JAVA:17-java17' --resource-group 'siliconrg11' -p 'ASP-siliconrg11-88b2' --os-type 'Linux'
            

      - run:
          name: Deploy Code
          command: |
            ls -rlt ~/repo/build/libs/app.jar
            az webapp deploy --resource-group siliconrg11 --name valleywebapp32 --type jar --src-path <path to jar>

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main
```

In the `az webapp up` command, Make sure you are passing the entire folder and you have configured your yml script to run the command from the root, I ran the command from the root and all my files with JAR file got deployed successfully in Azure Web app, Refer below:-

```bash
ls
cd site
cd wwwroot
cd gradle
cd wrapper
ls
```

[image]

In `az webapp deploy` make sure to select type as **JAR** and `src-path` to **your jar file** and check if it gets deployed sucessfully, You can run these commands locally before deploying it via CirceCI pipeline in a test app.

[image]